# second hard drive to be mouunted as /home/Videos

Tags: mount, directory, fstab, symbolic-link

i am wanting to know if i can make my second hard drive be the videos folder that is in my home dir. if so please tell me how.

mainly when i click on the videos folder i want it to show me the stuff on the 2nd drive (my videos)

is this an edit to my fstab and that is it or is their a symbolic link trick i need to do, i really dont want to mess around too much due to possibly loosing all my videos.  the big thing is i want plex be able to use it as well.

Answer (score 3):

Just make a symbolic link in your home folder to the videos drive like this:

```
rmdir "~/Videos" # Delete old videos folder

ln -s "/media/videos_drive" "~/Videos" # link videos folder to the drive
```

Replace `/media/videos_drive` with the path to your videos drive.